# python modual problem with terminal

Tags: pi-zero-w, python-3, terminal, failure

I have written this program in python:

```
print("CC ACTIVATED")
import lcddriver
import time
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
display = lcddriver.lcd()
try:
    display.lcd_display_string("CC... ", 1) 
    time.sleep(2)
    display.lcd_display_string("ONLINE", 2)
    time.sleep(2)
    display.lcd_clear()
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
try:
    display.lcd_display_string("SETUP A", 1) 
    display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD? Y/N", 2)
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
activate = input("")
if activate == 'y':
    print("ACTIVATED")
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("", 1) 
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_display_string("LOADING", 2)
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_clear()
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")

else:
    print("ABORT")
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("", 1) 
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_display_string("ABORT", 2)
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_clear()
        subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
        subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
k = True
while k:
    
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("ENTER PASSWORD", 1) 
        display.lcd_display_string("----------------", 2)
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
    pasword = input("")
    display.lcd_clear()
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("YOU TYPED:", 1) 
        display.lcd_display_string(pasword, 2)
        time.sleep(2)
        display.lcd_display_string("CONFIRM? Y/N", 1) 
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
    ok = input("")
    if ok == 'y':
        k = False
    else:
        display.lcd_clear()
try:
    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD", 1) 
    display.lcd_display_string("SET", 2)
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
time.sleep(2)
run = True
try:
    display.lcd_clear()
    display.lcd_display_string("STARTING ", 1) 
    display.lcd_display_string("GAME...", 2)
except Exception:
    print("SCREEN ERROR")
time.sleep(2)
password_attempts = 0
while run and password_attempts < 4:
    try:
        display.lcd_clear()
        display.lcd_display_string("ENTER PASSWORD ", 1) 
        display.lcd_display_string("TO DEACTIVATE", 2)
    except Exception:
        print("SCREEN ERROR")
    pasword1 = input("")
    if pasword1 == pasword:
        try:
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD....", 1)
            time.sleep(2)
            display.lcd_display_string("ACCEPTED", 2)
            time.sleep(2)
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("DEACTIVATED", 2)
            subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
            time.sleep(10)
        except Exception:
            print("SCREEN ERROR")
            subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
    else:
        password_attempts += 1
        try:
            display.lcd_clear()
            display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD....", 1)
            time.sleep(2)
            display.lcd_display_string("UNACCEPTED", 2)
            time.sleep(2)
        except Exception:
            print("SCREEN ERROR")
        if password_attempts == 3:
            last_request = datetime.now()
            current_request = datetime.now()
            while((current_request - last_request).total_seconds() < 5 * 60):
                #Code to play music
                current_request = datetime.now()
                try:
                    display.lcd_clear()
                    display.lcd_display_string("ENTER PASSWORD ", 1) 
                    display.lcd_display_string("TO DEACTIVATE", 2)
                except Exception:
                    print("SCREEN ERROR")
                pasword1 = input("")
                if pasword1 == pasword:
                    try:
                        display.lcd_clear()
                        display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD....", 1)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        display.lcd_display_string("ACCEPTED", 2)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        display.lcd_clear()
                        display.lcd_display_string("DEACTIVATED", 2)
                        subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
                        time.sleep(10)
                    except Exception:
                        print("SCREEN ERROR")
                        subprocess.call(["sudo","halt"])
                else:
                    if ((current_request - last_request).total_seconds() < 5 * 60):
                        password_attempts = 1
                        try:
                            display.lcd_clear()
                            display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD....", 1)
                            time.sleep(2)
                            display.lcd_display_string("UNACCEPTED", 2)
                            time.sleep(2)
                        except Exception:
                            print("SCREEN ERROR")
                        sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3('/home/pi/lcd/export_ofoct.com(1)-[AudioTrimmer.com](1).mp3')
                        play(sound)
                        print("ALARM")
                    else:
                        try:
                            display.lcd_clear()
                            display.lcd_display_string("PASSWORD....", 1)
                            time.sleep(2)
                            display.lcd_display_string("UNACCEPTED", 2)
                            time.sleep(2)
                        except Exception:
                            print("SCREEN ERROR")
                        print("NO ALARM")
```

When I run it with python3 idle everything works fine, but in the terminal I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/lcd/CC.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pydub import AudioSegment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydub'
```

I ran this command to install pydub:

```
pip3 install pydub
```

I just don't understand why it isn't working with the terminal. Is there a way to fix this?
This is the command I use:

```
python3 /home/lcd/CC.py
```

Comment: Are you sure you use python 3 on the command line? Use `python3` to start your script. BTW: please post *full* error messages in future. There is valuable info in there (most likely a reference to the python version)

Comment: @Dirk I am positive that I'm using python3 on the command line.

Comment: @Dirk p.s That's the entire error.

Comment: What user did you run the pip3 command as?  That needs to be the same as the user running the program unless you use `sudo pip3`  I see the code is in /home/lcd so I'm assuming you have created a user lcd and running the program under that so I may be 100% wrong here :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is NOT Pi specific, and you have NOT provided sufficient detail to actually provide a definitive solution. The following is most likely the cause.

Unless pydub.py is in the same directory as your program it should be in a directory on the PYTHONPATH, **BUT** it is preferable to install with `sudo pip3 install pydub` so it is available to all users/programs.